# Joomla 1.7 eleven45 template now displaying in IE8 and 9

Tags: internet-explorer, templates, joomla1.7

Having trouble here testing this new design in IE 8 and 9. Using Windows 7 here with Internet Explorer version 9. Switching between browser and document modes in the developer console but the site doesn't seem to load. I am using the fancy eleven45 template to start with. Can anyone shed some light on this issue. I'm sure it's something ridiculously silly. Thanks in advance.

http://www.viridian-graphics.com/grind_hard/

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to fix your doctype declaration because it affects how IE determines whether to use compatibility mode or not. Generally in Joomla this works -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

You can also control compatibility mode with a meta tag. Here is a good read on doctype and how it affects compatibility mode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242%28VS.85%29.aspx

Here is info on how to define what mode the browser uses for your site - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: No luck on either of those links. Using doctype html ensures the widest compatibility among all browsers and the syntax is correct. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

It's gotta be something else. Not sure what.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case we need to get back to basics. Switch to one of the default Joomla templates and see if that works. If it does, then there is an issue in the template code. If not, then you will need to start turning off extensions until the site does load.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! I isolated the issue to a few specific modules. Saw that the fonts were giving IE trouble. It seems that my version of Helvetica doesn't jive with IE 9. It's a Type 1 font. Not sure if all Type 1 fonts have trouble with IE. I'm assuming yes, but I don't know for sure. Three days wasted on that issue, but at least I know YET ANOTHER bug with IE.

http://oddballupdate.com/2011/08/13/internet-explorer-9-helvetica-type-1-and-you/

Thanks for all your help Brent. Got me kicked off in the right direction.